# Making a progress bar in a circle

Tags: jquery, html, css

I need to make a 'health' progress bar for a project, where green represents the filled in data and red the empty data. I got a nice circle when the red part is 50%, but as soon as that value changes to anything else the border-radius is all messed up..

Here is what I have at the moment:

HTML:

```
<div id="progressWrap">
    <span class="progressRed"></span>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#progressWrap {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  display: block;
  background-color: forestgreen;
  -webkit-border-radius: 100%;
  -moz-border-radius: 100%;
  -ms-border-radius: 100%; 
  border-radius: 100%;
}
.progressRed {
    width: 50%;
    height: 50px;
    float: right;
    background-color: red;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 25px;
    border-top-right-radius: 25px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/q48Qf/

The width value of the progressRed class is going to be dynamic with Jquery, perhaps I could alter the border-radius as well to make it fit the progressWrap again? I just wouldn't know how to calculate the border-radius needed in that case.

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Why don't you try pie chart for this. many jQuery plugins available. one of them is here : http://www.jqplot.com/tests/pie-donut-charts.php

Comment: Here is a nice article on what you are trying to do: [http://css-tricks.com/css-pie-timer/](http://css-tricks.com/css-pie-timer/)

Comment: Nah I dont want the circle to fill pie-wise but the red part will cover a % of the circle's surface. Andreas Carlbom's answer was the one I was looking for :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The red part doesn't need a border radius. Since it's wrapped entirely in the green circle, it's easier to just let it stay a square and hide the overflow from the parent.

Set `overflow: hidden` on the parent (green) part, and remove the radii from the red.

Example:  http://jsfiddle.net/q48Qf/3/

Comment: Wow, so easy.. Thanks! This is exactly what I was looking for :) Will make this the accepted answer when I can